# Python How to Capture All Output from Command Line Calls

Tags: python, command-line, subprocess

I'm trying to, from a python script, check if a system has anaconda installed.

My thought on how to do this is to call 'which conda' from the python script and get the output.

Seems like this is impossible though for some reason. On my computer (2015 Macbook Pro running High Sierra), it appears that calling this throws some kind of error. This would be no problem, except that python seems to under no circumstances be able to capture error output from calls.

I've tried subprocess.call, os.system, subprocess.run, subprocess.check_call, subprocess.check_output.

In all of these cases, despite claims that you can forward error output to stdout with stderr=subprocess.PIPE or stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, I have been able to get all of nothing from any of these calls.

I can see on my command line, when I call 'which conda', that it outputs a great body of text.

In python, even when I catch errors as instructed, the output is a blank string.

It is incredibly frustrating because this seems like such an unbelievably simple thing to do; and I've spent so much time on it now. It can be done on the command line. Why can it not be done in this high level language?

Any help/tips are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: When you are printing out the output from subprocess, you are printing out  `s.stdout` for subprocess object `s`, right?

Answer (score 3):

I don't have anaconda... I just replaced with python:

```
>>> from os import popen
>>> cmd = "which python"
>>> for i in popen(cmd):
...     print(i)
... 
/usr/bin/python
```

You could also do something like this to get the last part of the path:

```
from os import path, popen
cmd = "which python"
>>> for i in popen(cmd):
...     print(path.basename(i))
... 
python
```

This one also worked for me:

```
>>> for i in popen('whereis python'):
...     for j in i.split():
...         print(j)
... 
python:
/usr/bin/python2.7-config
/usr/bin/python3.5
/usr/bin/python3.5m
/usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/python2.7
/usr/bin/python3.5m-config
/usr/bin/python3.5-config
/usr/lib/python3.5
/usr/lib/python2.7
/etc/python3.5
/etc/python
/etc/python2.7
/usr/local/lib/python3.5
/usr/local/lib/python2.7
/usr/include/python3.5
/usr/include/python3.5m
/usr/include/python2.7
/usr/share/python
/usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz
```